# Unable to load one-hot labels in a torchtext iterator ( ValueError: too many dimensions 'str')

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchtext

My "label" field is a one-hot vector of 201 length. I am however unable to create an iterator with this one-hot representation. I'm getting the below error if I try to iterate over the iterator.

```
from torchtext.data import Field
from torchtext.data import TabularDataset
from torchtext.data import Iterator, BucketIterator

tokenize = lambda x: x.split()

TEXT = Field(sequential=True, tokenize=tokenize, lower=True)

LABEL = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=False)

datafields = [("text", TEXT), ("label", LABEL)]

train, test = TabularDataset.splits(
               path = '/home/karthik/Documents/Deep_Learning/73Strings/',
               train = "train.csv", validation="test.csv",
               format='csv',
               skip_header=True, 
               fields=datafields)

train_iter, val_iter = BucketIterator.splits(
 (train, test), # we pass in the datasets we want the iterator to draw data from
 batch_sizes=(64, 64),
 device=device, # if you want to use the GPU, specify the GPU number here
 sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text), # the BucketIterator needs to be told what function it should use to group the data.
 sort_within_batch=False,
 repeat=False # we pass repeat=False because we want to wrap this Iterator layer.
)
test_iter = Iterator(test, batch_size=64, sort=False, sort_within_batch=False, repeat=False)

for batch in train_iter:
    print(batch)
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 for batch in train_iter:
      2     print(batch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/iterator.py in **iter**(self)
    155                     else:
    156                         minibatch.sort(key=self.sort_key, reverse=True)
--> 157                 yield Batch(minibatch, self.dataset, self.device)
    158             if not self.repeat:
    159                 return

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/batch.py in **init**(self, data, dataset, device)
     32                 if field is not None:
     33                     batch = [getattr(x, name) for x in data]
---> 34                     setattr(self, name, field.process(batch, device=device))
     35 
     36     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/field.py in process(self, batch, device)
    199         """
    200         padded = self.pad(batch)
--> 201         tensor = self.numericalize(padded, device=device)
    202         return tensor
    203

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/field.py in numericalize(self, arr, device)
    321                 arr = self.postprocessing(arr, None)
    322 
--> 323         var = torch.tensor(arr, dtype=self.dtype, device=device)
    324 
    325         if self.sequential and not self.batch_first:

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by changing `LABEL = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=False)` into `LABEL = Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False)` . This worked for me.

> sequential – Whether the datatype represents sequential data. If False, no tokenization is applied. Default: True.

https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#field